# I would like to get the text of the button (of youtube) "subscribe"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, subscribe

I would like to get the text of the button (of youtube) "subscribe"
in a textbox in c #
example I open the form
and I receive this button text,
that is "subscribe"
in a textbox.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

{
            try
            {
                string url = this.textBoxLink.Text;
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                this.richTextBoxSC.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string imgpath = this.SearchY(this.richTextBoxSC, "thumbnailUl", 20, "\">").ToString();
                this.pictureBoxThumb.ImageLocation = imgpath;
                string title = this.SearchY(this.richTextBoxSC, "", 25, "

").ToString();
                if (title.Contains("\""))
                {
                    title = this.SearchY(this.richTextBoxSC, "class=\"style-scope ytd-subscribe-button-renderer\"", 60, "

```
            }
```

Comment: this manages to capture
the title of a video
and also the video image (thumbnail)
(obviously inserting the video link)
but I can not capture
the text of the button